# Centralize macros using \shortex from lingmacros (or using a different package)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, lingmacros

I'm trying to centralize the macro that I write using the `\shortex` from `\usepackage{lingmacros}`, to get a result similar to this:

[image]

Unfortunatly, my result is quite different:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\eenumsentence{\shortex{8}
{John & may & have & Perf & be & Part & come & often}
{$n_{3}$ & $(n_{3}\backslash s_{1})/i$ & $i/q$ & $q/i$ & $i/p$ & $p/i$ & $i$ & $i\backslash i$}{}}
\end{center}
```

What I'm doing wrong, and what can I do to fix this problem? if this can't be done using `lingmacros`, how can it be done using another package (e.g. gb4e?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `lingmacros` commands are probably the best solution for this if you also want to centre the example itself without a number. The package already defines a `\shortexnt` command which is like `\shortex` but without the third line. Since you're not using that line anyway, there's not need to use `\shortex`.  It's also not clear that you need the `\enumsentence` so I've removed it.

In this example I've redefined `\shortexnt` to centre align the words. I've also added an extra blank column to make the spacing a bit nicer between `may` and `have`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\renewcommand{\shortexnt}[3]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}*{#1}{c@{\ }}}
#2\\ #3
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\shortexnt{9}
{John & may & & have & Perf & be & Part & come & often}
{$n_{3}$ &  $(n_{3}\backslash s_{1})/i$ & & $i/q$ & $q/i$ & $i/p$ & $p/i$ & $i$ & $i\backslash i$}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of lingmacros code]

If you are using regular numbered examples rather than centred unnumbered examples, then the ExPex package might be a better solution, since it will automatically align things on spaces (like other glossing macros).  Here's an example done that way. It will not allow you to centre the whole example, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expex}

\begin{document}
\ex
\begingl[glwordalign=center,everygla=\rmfamily]
\gla John  may {}  have  Perf  be  Part  come  often//
\glb $n_{3}$  $(n_{3}\backslash s_{1})/i$ {} $i/q$  $q/i$  $i/p$  $p/i$  $i$  $i\backslash i$//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

[image: output of expex code]